# NativeScript Angular lazy loaded modules using Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, lazy-loading, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to implement lazy loading of feature modules in my NativeScript + Angular application. I'm wondering if I have to do some additional Webpack setup to make lazy loading work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6/7 by default uses Eager/Lazy loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332996/angular-6-7-by-default-uses-eager-lazy-loading)

Answer (score 2):

There is no additional setup required for NativeScript + Angular, it's just as simple as how you would do it in a web app.